# How to automatically switch back from Display view to Console in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am working with Eclipse Luna and sometimes use the Display view during debug to evaluate certain expressions. Eclipse was always switching back to Console after I performed the evaluation (pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). But now I have to manually switch back to Console view to see the result.

Any idea how to make Eclipse switch back to Console view automatically after executing an expression in Display view?